# media queries not working in safari or chrome. working fine in firefox

Tags: firefox, media

http://timenoplace.com/releases/

this is a site i am working on.

media queries are working perfectly in firefox and not in safari or chrome.

if you drop the width to below 960 - you will see the background turn yellow in firefox... but in safari and chrome, the changes do not register.

i have never had this problem before.  it is driving me insane.

can't find anything online ... does anyone have any ideas ???  css validates...

the project is a theme i built for wordpress.  could that have anything to do with this?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your style.css on line 282, you have a block for `@media screen {` without a closing `}`. Add the closing bracket after your css rules for the media screen (line 1320) - that should do the trick.

I guess firefox, unlike chrome and safari, isn't too picky about syntax.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!  i have never wrapped my main css in @media screen - but i saw chris coyier doing it and i was trying it out - and then forgot about that bracket !!!!!!!!!!   i was going insane - looking at all my other responsive sites over and over again -  THANK YOU !!!