# CSS style from second css files not being applied in Safari

Tags: css, html, safari

In my webpage I have three CSS files. There are linked like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/min480.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/max480.css" type="text/css">
```

In Safari (Mac and Windows) the styles from the second (and third) CSS file are not being applied. However, its working fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera. Could this happen because of @media?

The website is: http://bit.ly/basementproj

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826564/media-queries-not-working-in-safari-or-chrome-working-fine-in-firefox

Comment: I had seen that link before, since you mentioned it again, that link got me to go through each and every line of code in my CSS, and turns out... I did miss one close }. Sometimes solving a problem is about not being lazy and getting your hands dirty!!! Thanks @NathanLee

Comment: You are welcome :) Making hands dirty is very important to know the root cause of the issue and yes, being lazy does not serve the purpose on a routine check - @Teejay

Comment: yeah, well the weird thing is, the website has been working for a couple of months with no issues. I decided on improve my YSlow score, and so did a minification and unification of my css files, that seemed to have broken it :S! Which is also why i ruled that solution out. Anywho im glad i learned that sometimes the solution can be the one thats most obvious. Thanks again @NathanLee